# HTTP form on HTTPS page

Tags: php, html, http, https

I have a mailchimp subscribe form on the footer of my website at all times. This includes HTTPS pages during checkout.

I wanted to link to the form using HTTPS but when I do the link does not work. But if I don't link https then I will show an insecure page on checkout:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://compant.us2.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=5513172da1aaasda4fdedba&amp;id=1234" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL"><?php echo MENU_SIGN_UP_FOR_THE_LATEST_ANZIE_NEWS; ?></label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="<?php echo MENU_EMAIL_ADDRESS; ?>" required>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo MENU_SUBSCRIBE; ?>" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: What link doesn't work? There's no link here.

Comment: @ceejayoz The form Action

Comment: Have you considered adding HTTPS to *your* site? It's better for your users, better for your Google ranking, and it's free these days.

Comment: Simple, you can't use an HTTPS action to mailchimp. I use that service also. So the answer to this here is just that. Would you like me to post this in the answers area?

Comment: Actually, there was an existing duplicate for this which says the same thing I said, plus more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
<form action="https://ostraining.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=c4fe34ed80790dd773846d4e1&amp;id=e030bfa9b8
```

Taken from https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/mailchimp-forms-ssl/

Comment: Doesn't that just say "use the protocoll used on the site"?

Comment: There is also a change from list-manage1 to list-manage. Both of the cahnges are needed for SSL to work

Comment: If the OP eventually does get an SSL certificate and has their page on an HTTPS socket, this will fail.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This actually seems to work. All pages are HTTPS on my site. And changing the URL as well as the list-manage1 to list-manage seems to work.